# Error al llamar a una función del postgres con node-odoo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, postgresql, npm, odoo

estoy haciendo una web para conectarme contra odoo, pero al intentar llamar a una función de postgres, que equivale a un procedimiento almacenado de sql, no logro hacer que esta funcione, me salta siempre el mismo error, este es mi código:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Odoo = require('node-odoo');

var odoo = new Odoo({
    host: 'host',
    port: 1111,
    database: 'prueba1',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin'
});


odoo.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }

    let partner = odoo.get('funcion_prueba', 'valorPrueba', (err, partner) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(partner);
        return partner;
    });

    console.log(partner);
});


module.exports = app;
```

El error que me salta es el siguiente:

```
{ code: 200,
    message: 'Odoo Server Error',
    data:
     { name: 'builtins.KeyError',
       debug:
        'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/odoo/http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception\n    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception\n    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise\n    raise value\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/odoo/http.py", line 669, in dispatch\n    result = self._call_function(**self.params)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function\n    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper\n    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call\n    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/odoo/http.py", line 915, in 
  __call__\n    return self.method(*args, **kw)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap\n    response = f(*args, **kw)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1318, in call\n    return self._call_kw(model, method, 
  args, {})\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1314, in _call_kw\n    return call_kw(request.env[model], 
  method, args, kwargs)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/odoo/api.py", line 463, in __getitem__\n    return self.registry[model_name]._browse(self, (), ())\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13-prueba1/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 177, in __getitem__\n    return self.models[model_name]\nKeyError: \'funcion_prueba\'\n',
       message: 'funcion_prueba',
       arguments: [ 'funcion_prueba' ],
       exception_type: 'internal_error',
       context: {} } }
```

Como podría hacer para que me funcionase el llamar a una función?? muchas gracias

Comment: Echale un ojo a la documentación del modulo. Quizas la definición del get() tenga que ser de otra forma. https://github.com/monksoftware/node-odoo-client @Yandrak

Comment: Pero no logro llamar a ninguna funcion, quiero hacer algo tipo odoo.call('myFunct', (err, result) => {});

Pero no logro encontrar nada parecido ni en la documentación